# How to center two text columns in CSS.

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, center

i have a problem centering these two text columns so that they stand beside each other can anybody help me with this issue, i managed to do it previously by setting the padding, margin manually, but of course i want it to be work on all formats.

here is the code for the css (i have deleted most of the useless css but i don't know what to use.)

```
.AboutBA {
text-align: justify;
position: relative;
display:inline;
}

.Position {
text-align: justify;
display: inline;
}
```

and here is for the html

```
<div class="container">

<div class="AboutBA">
<h3>About BrandAmb</h3>
<p><i>BrandAmb</i> is a Danish marketing company  whose<br/> goal mission is to help both Danish and foreign<br/> brands expand their brand in Scandinavia through<br/> social marketing. By analyzing and studying your<br/> brand and the audience that you are trying to reach<br/> we, through our database of ambassadors, connects<br/> your brand with one or several of our brandambassadors.<br/> By using their broad platform our brandambassadors<br/> will help your brand reach the audience that is at target<br/> and get your brand the recognition that it deservs in<br/> Scandinavia. <a href="About-us.html">Read more about us.</a></p>
</div>

<div class="Position">
<h3>Our position</h3>
<p>When it comes to our position between your brand and<br/> our brandambassors we can have two potions depening<br/> on what your seeking as a brand. The first position is<br/> merely as an intermediary between your brand and our<br/> ambassadors. That means that we create and find the<br/> right connection and make sure it's a match, but the<br/> rest is up to you. Our second position is more hands-on.<br/> By using our cultural knowledge we can, if requested,<br/> help make a stragegy to fit excactly your targeted<br/> audiance in the Scandinavian market. Furthermore we<br/> help with communication between the two parties so any<br/> cultural or communication barriers are avoided.<br/><a href="products.html">Read about our products.</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of the layout]

thx in advance

regards kristoffer

Comment: Why don't you add a common class to both elements and `display` them `inline-block`, with `vertical-align: top` and a `width` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for non responsive sites. If you would like it responsive, you can modify it with some media queries or use a responsive framework such as foundation to define the width at different viewport sizes, such as large-6 / medium-6 / small-12 etc

```css
.container {
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.content {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="AboutBA content">
<h3>About BrandAmb</h3>
<p><i>BrandAmb</i> is a Danish marketing company  whose<br/> goal mission is to help both Danish and foreign<br/> brands expand their brand in Scandinavia through<br/> social marketing. By analyzing and studying your<br/> brand and the audience that you are trying to reach<br/> we, through our database of ambassadors, connects<br/> your brand with one or several of our brandambassadors.<br/> By using their broad platform our brandambassadors<br/> will help your brand reach the audience that is at target<br/> and get your brand the recognition that it deservs in<br/> Scandinavia. <a href="About-us.html">Read more about us.</a></p>
</div>

<div class="Position content">
<h3>Our position</h3>
<p>When it comes to our position between your brand and<br/> our brandambassors we can have two potions depening<br/> on what your seeking as a brand. The first position is<br/> merely as an intermediary between your brand and our<br/> ambassadors. That means that we create and find the<br/> right connection and make sure it's a match, but the<br/> rest is up to you. Our second position is more hands-on.<br/> By using our cultural knowledge we can, if requested,<br/> help make a stragegy to fit excactly your targeted<br/> audiance in the Scandinavian market. Furthermore we<br/> help with communication between the two parties so any<br/> cultural or communication barriers are avoided.<br/><a href="products.html">Read about our products.</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The '.content' class is simply a reusable class to assign a 50% width to that is applicable to both columns. However, a responsive framework would certainly help clean up the code. I've just created another example for you using foundation. And this is fully responsive. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzpwmV

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap Grid](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width).

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>About BrandAmb</h3>
    <p><i>BrandAmb</i> is a Danish marketing company  whose<br/> goal mission is to help both Danish and foreign<br/> brands expand their brand in Scandinavia through<br/> social marketing. By analyzing and studying your<br/> brand and the audience that you are trying to reach<br/> we, through our database of ambassadors, connects<br/> your brand with one or several of our brandambassadors.<br/> By using their broad platform our brandambassadors<br/> will help your brand reach the audience that is at target<br/> and get your brand the recognition that it deservs in<br/> Scandinavia. <a href="About-us.html">Read more about us.</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Our position</h3>
    <p>When it comes to our position between your brand and<br/> our brandambassors we can have two potions depening<br/> on what your seeking as a brand. The first position is<br/> merely as an intermediary between your brand and our<br/> ambassadors. That means that we create and find the<br/> right connection and make sure it's a match, but the<br/> rest is up to you. Our second position is more hands-on.<br/> By using our cultural knowledge we can, if requested,<br/> help make a stragegy to fit excactly your targeted<br/> audiance in the Scandinavian market. Furthermore we<br/> help with communication between the two parties so any<br/> cultural or communication barriers are avoided.<br/><a href="products.html">Read about our products.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex also.To be responsive you have to had "flex-wrap: wrap" property to the container and a min-width for the text.

```css
.container
{
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
}

.AboutBA {
text-align: center;
width:50%;

}

.Position {
text-align: center;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="AboutBA">
<h3>About BrandAmb</h3>
<p><i>BrandAmb</i> is a Danish marketing company  whose<br/> goal mission is to help both Danish and foreign<br/> brands expand their brand in Scandinavia through<br/> social marketing. By analyzing and studying your<br/> brand and the audience that you are trying to reach<br/> we, through our database of ambassadors, connects<br/> your brand with one or several of our brandambassadors.<br/> By using their broad platform our brandambassadors<br/> will help your brand reach the audience that is at target<br/> and get your brand the recognition that it deservs in<br/> Scandinavia. <a href="About-us.html">Read more about us.</a></p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="Position">
<h3>Our position</h3>
<p>When it comes to our position between your brand and<br/> our brandambassors we can have two potions depening<br/> on what your seeking as a brand. The first position is<br/> merely as an intermediary between your brand and our<br/> ambassadors. That means that we create and find the<br/> right connection and make sure it's a match, but the<br/> rest is up to you. Our second position is more hands-on.<br/> By using our cultural knowledge we can, if requested,<br/> help make a stragegy to fit excactly your targeted<br/> audiance in the Scandinavian market. Furthermore we<br/> help with communication between the two parties so any<br/> cultural or communication barriers are avoided.<br/><a href="products.html">Read about our products.</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```